# Zend\Permissions\Rbac\Role Error 500 when try to instantiate object

Tags: zend-framework3, rbac

I'm trying to implement a RBAC in my project, but I can't instantiate Rbac class.

My code:

```
<?php
```

namespace Login\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\Permissions\Rbac\Rbac;
use Zend\Permissions\Rbac\Role;

class TesteController extends AbstractActionController {

```
public function indexAction() {
    $role = new Role('teste');

    die('=== FIM ===');
}
```

}

When I comment the Role line it shows "=== FIM ===", but when it isn't commented it gives 500 error.

I already check the module struct in vendor and it's alright.

Do I need to do anything else when I install a vendor module via composer to zend 3 recognize it?

Comment: Can you please share your code of composer.json, module.config.php inside module/Application/Conficonfi and module specific config files for better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was cause by my php version that doesn't accept return type declarations. The Rbac module is full of it.